# PDF Creation using Diagnostics.Process and Wkhtmltopdf slow on server

Tags: pdf, wkhtmltopdf, system.diagnostics

People,

I’m generating a PDF file within a .NET application using wkhtmltopdf inside a  System.Diagnostics.Process

While this process takes approx. 1 sec to run on my local machine (Win 10 Pro 16gb mem) once deployed to server and using the same data it takes approx. 40 secs on the server (win server 2012 8gb mem). The resultant PDF file in both cases is only about 34kb.

Have run some diagnostics times on each code line I have found that it is this line which takes all the time.

```
if (!process.WaitForExit(120000))
```

I have tried changing permissions on output folder and also changing output folder. I have also change identity on IIS application pool.
With such a disparity in performance I’m not convinced it is code issue just configuration. Can anyone shed any light on this.
Slightly abbreviated code below
I should also mention that I have run procmon on server while running at appears to be doing very little after originally loading program.

```
        var temp = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~//temppdf//")

        var outputPdfFilePath = Path.Combine(temp,
                String.Format("{0}.pdf", Guid.NewGuid()));

        document.Url = "-";

        ProcessStartInfo si;

        StringBuilder paramsBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        paramsBuilder.Append("--page-size A4 ");
        paramsBuilder.Append("--zoom 1.000 ");
        paramsBuilder.Append("--disable-smart-shrinking ");
        paramsBuilder.AppendFormat("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", document.Url, outputPdfFilePath);

        si = new ProcessStartInfo();
        si.CreateNoWindow = false;
        si.FileName = environment.WkHtmlToPdfPath; //path to exe in programs file(x86)
        si.Arguments = paramsBuilder.ToString();
        si.UseShellExecute = false;
        si.RedirectStandardError = false;
        si.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        try
        {
            using (var process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = si;
                process.Start();
                if (document.Html != null)
                    using (var stream = process.StandardInput)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(document.Html);
                        stream.BaseStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        stream.WriteLine();
                    }

                if (!process.WaitForExit(120000))
                    throw new PdfConvertTimeoutException();
                // THis above command takes 1 sec locally and 42 secs on server
            }

        }
        finally
        {
                if (delete && File.Exists(outputPdfFilePath))File.Delete(outputPdfFilePath);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well finally got to the bottom of this and had absolutely nothing to do with the code. It transpires that the HTML I was trying to convert had links to images on a live website. While this website was accessible from my local machine it was inaccessible from the server. Therefore time delay due to timeouts trying to access inaccessible images.

Doh!!!